# Status code 400 with my GET request - Mixpanel API

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, mixpanel

I am new to python so please be kind! I'm trying to get event data from Mixpanel's export API. I've been able to do this successfully in Talend and Postman but I want to be able to program it in Python.

Try as I might, I'm having no luck. I keep getting a status code of 400.

```
import requests
import base64

enc = base64.b64encode(b'my-api-secret').decode("ascii")
headers = {f'Authorization': 'Basic {enc}'}
data = {
  'from_date': '2019-02-01',
  'to_date': '2019-02-03'
}
response = requests.get('https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/', data=data, auth=headers)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're doing something wrong in sending the post data. `HTTP 400` means __Bad Request__, which indicates the you're making the wrong kind of request. Are you sure the post data is like that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you mean the headers by post data?

Comment: I've solved it now...

I needed to do this:

`response = requests.post('https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/', data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(apisecret,''))`

If anyone can help me to understand why, that would be appreciated. I am guessing my base 64 encoding method wasn't needed because of the 'auth='...

Also don't understand why post worked....I'm _getting_ data from this API, not _posting_ anything?